# Please explain the associativity of the operators in this code

Tags: c, associativity

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char s[] = {'a','b','c','\n','c','\0'};
  char *p;
  p=&s[3];
  printf("%d\t",++*p++);
  printf("%d",*p);
  return 0;
}
```

output: 11  99
Please explain the output. Why there is an increment in the address?

Comment: where do you have this horrific code from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator Precedence.. () and ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897934/operator-precedence-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I see that could possibly be confusing is

```
++*p++
```

Postincrement has higher precedence than the dereference operator, so fully parenthesized it looks like

```
++(*(p++))
```

Which postincrements `p`, dereferences the original value of `p` to get a `char`, then preincrements the value of the `char`, and then the new value gets printed by `printf` as an integer.

So both `p` and what `p` is pointing at get incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the operator precedences.
The expression `++*p++` is evaluated as`((*p) + 1)` by the compiler, and it also have a side-effect: it increments the value of `*p` and `p`. With a ASCII-compatible charset, this instruction prints `11` (`'\n'+1 == 10+1 == 11`) on the standard output. The second `printf` call prints the value of `s[4]` (`'c'`).

Answer (score 0):

pointers in C are just integers which represent a memory location. Arrays in C are always in continuous memory blocks. So when you have a pointer which points to the third element of an array, and you add 1 from the pointer, it points at the fourth element.

In case you are confused about `++*p++`: That's because of the different between pre-increment `(++p)` and post-increment `(p++)`. There is an easy moniker for that for people who hate C++:

> "C++ - change the language, return the old problems".